# 'Tears for' or 'Tears of'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was trying to write some poetry and I wonder if I can say:

> Perch on my lashes
> My tears for the wrench.

I am talking about the last line. Can we say "tears for something" like "tears for sadness"? Or should I say "tears of something" like "tears of sadness"? And can I use "wrench" here to denote sadness caused by leaving someone?

Comment: I see "for" being used in situations where the sadness/anger/whatever are caused by that thing, whereas "of" is the immediate emotion (the sadness itself). Also "for" can mean "on behalf of". That is, empathetic crying for some other person or thing. I would never say "tears of a wrench" btw.

Comment: "[Wrench](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrench)" often means a tool, so "tears for the wrench" suggests you've lost your spanner.

Comment: You can say what you like in poetry, and there might be occasions where it fits (in a punning poem about a tragicomic plumber, it's great). For it to be good poetry, you need to consider all the connotations of the words. That kind of writing advice or literary discussion is off-topic here though.

Comment: I've added the [prepositions] tag since you're asking about choosing between *for* and *of*. Please review the [tag help](/tags/prepositions/info) because using the wrong preposition can dramatically alter the meaning of the phrase. You haven't explained in your question what you actually want the phrase to mean.

Comment: It's **wench** you should be writing about: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wench

Comment: It's the first line I'm puzzled by

Comment: It's wrenching away from someone, like tearing off a plaster, which is causing tears to appear on the eyelashes. Perhaps the preposition should be *at,* though.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: It makes more sense (to me at least) if you reverse the two lines: "My tears... perch on my (eye)lashes"